# How to make unity 2d repeating world in game Top Down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently making a Top Down Shooter game and I need the card not to run out, I have 4 pieces of ready-made cards and I need them to appear randomly. I would like to use Object Pool. I can't handle it in any way. Please help me. There is a basic code. Help me finish the code pls.

```
private float _spawnRadius = 7;

[SerializeField] private Transform _pointTop;
[SerializeField] private Transform _pointRight;

[SerializeField] private GameObject _prefab;

void Update()
{
    Vector2 spawnPos = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform.position;
    spawnPos += new Vector2(_pointRight.position.x, _pointTop.position.y) * _spawnRadius;

    Instantiate(_prefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
}`
```

I tried all the ways, but I can't do anything to create objects behind the camera, but it turns out that it is just being created on the spot. I hope my problem was clear to you!

Comment: 1. This is NOT object pooling, 2. It's very bad to call any "Find" function in the update(), instead cache it at start or awake, and/or check for null in the update and then find it ONCE.  and lastly: I don't understand what you want to do, or what is the error you are getting, please read, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is clearly in `c#`

Comment: to add to @Wolfeius  comment ... pretty sure you also do NOT want to call `Instantiate` every frame!